# Detect touch gesture in youtubeplayerview full screen

Tags: android, touch-event

I'm trying to detect swipe gesture of youtubeplayerview and change video played. When youtubepalyerview isn't in full screen mode, I can detected the touch gesture. But when it's in full screen mode, the touch gesture is not detected by the listener.

I tried to add youtubeplayerview in viewgroup and implement onintercepttouchevent. When it's not in full screen mode, the touch event is intercepted by my viewgroup. But when it's in full screen mode, only when the pause overlay appears, the touch is detected, ie. when I touch the full screen, overlay appears and the touch event is lost from my viewgroup.

Why is my viewgroup not capturing the touch event when it's in full screen?

Comment: I am looking for a similar solution. Where you able to get your answer?

Comment: In fullscreen mode, first touch is always intercepted by youtubeplayerview.

Comment: I gave an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031817/swipe-gesture-are-not-working-in-youtubeplayerview-in-full-screen-mode. Please take a look.