# Adding onClickListener to YouTubePlayerView fullScreen mode

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I am using the [Youtube API for Android](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer). I want to add an `onClickListener` to the `YouTubePlayerView`, which works fine.

```
youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.player);
youTubePlayerView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
youTubePlayerView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

When clicking the video, it triggers the onClickListener. However, when I enable fullscreen mode, my activity no longer receives the onClick events.

```
private YouTubePlayer player;
...
player.setFullscreen(true);
```

My guess is that it uses a separate view for fullscreen. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I gave a solution here that might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031817/swipe-gesture-are-not-working-in-youtubeplayerview-in-full-screen-mode